# Is parallel compression of zipfile entries supported by minizip-ng

Tags: minizip

Does minizip or minizip-ng support compressing zipfile entries separately in parallel and then inserting them in the zipfile using minizip-ng.

I read the documentation of minizip-ng but cannot find a clear answers to confirm or disconfirm support for parallel compression of multiple zipfile entries

Comment: It's open source, why don't you check https://github.com/zlib-ng/minizip-ng ?

Comment: That was i did and there is no mentioning of how create zip entries in parallel processing